# Rollup bundle causes runtime errors

Tags: javascript, vite, rollup

I'm trying to bundle a library called [langium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/langium) using rollup.

It bundles correctly but then the resulting bundle causes a runtime error.

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at requireCompletionParserBuilder (user-of-langium.js:47901:11)
    at requireDefaultModule (user-of-langium.js:50827:38)
    at requireGrammarUtil (user-of-langium.js:29791:27)
    at requireGeneratorTracing (user-of-langium.js:15009:25)
    at requireNodeProcessor (user-of-langium.js:15155:30)
    at user-of-langium.js:15880:29
    at requireGeneratorNode (user-of-langium.js:16299:6)
    at requireTypes (user-of-langium.js:16321:27)
    at user-of-langium.js:18420:18
```

Here is my rollup configuration:

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/user-of-langium.js',
  output: {
    dir: '.dist',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({ browser: true }),
    commonjs(),
  ]
};
```

I don't know if I need to configure something or what is causing the issue.

I also have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nfc7cf) reproducing the error using vitejs that uses rollup to build the bundle.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I can set `strictRequires` to `true` in the commonjs plugin.

```js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/user-of-langium.js',
  output: {
    dir: '.dist',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({ browser: true }),
    commonjs({ strictRequires: true ),
  ]
};
```